# How do you do a line in JavaFX from one corner to its opposite one?

Tags: java, javafx, line

I would like to do `drawLine(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight())` in JavaFX. I do not just want to put numbers in my line. Here are the code for JFrame and JavaFX.

```
package project;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class main extends JPanel{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame myWindow = new JFrame("Isometric Grid");
        main myPanel = new main(); //myPanel is just a name

        myWindow.setSize(400,400);
        myWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myWindow.add(myPanel);
        myWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    //this method will override main and create a custom graphic
    public void paintComponent(Graphics myPen) //change
    {
        super.paintComponent(myPen);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);  
        myPen.setColor(Color.blue);

        myPen.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

I don't want to do this:

```
package JavaFXApplication14;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication14 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        Line ln = new Line(0,0,480,480);
        ln.setStrokeWidth(1);    
        root.getChildren().add(ln);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 480, 480, Color.SKYBLUE); 

        primaryStage.setTitle("Stuff");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Other questions I have is how to do getHeight(); in a for loop in JavaFX like:

```
for(int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y = y + 100)
```

And would it be possible to do something like this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Group root = new Group();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 480, 480, Color.SKYBLUE); 
    primaryStage.setTitle("Stuff");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    int x = (int) scene.getWidth(); 
    int y = (int) scene.getHeight(); 

    Line ln = new Line(0, 0, x, y); //480s dont matter
    ln.setStrokeWidth(1);
    root.getChildren().add(ln);

}
```

Comment: What is the problem woth the code that you don't want to use?

Comment: He has 480,480 hardcoded in JavaFX case, but probably would like to react to changing size of window dynamically.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski: ah, OP is using "line" for two very different purposes :)

Answer (score 5):

You do the same thing except with the Scene's width and height.  You can't use the group since it resizes itself to contain the line.  Another trick is bind to the width and height so you can resize the stage.  So after the Scene is declared add these next 2 lines.

```
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 480, 480, Color.SKYBLUE); 
    ln.endXProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
    ln.endYProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
```

If you don't want it bound it's just `ln.setEndX(scene.getWidth());`

For rectangles,

```
    for(int y = 0; y < scene.getHeight(); y += 20) { 
        //Rectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20, y, 10, 10);
        //default is black fill but you can chamge it;
        rect.setFill(Color.RED);
        //or in css, same as this
        rect.setStyle("-fx-fill: purple;");
        //then add it to the Group
        root.getChildren().add(rect);
    }
```

Comment: It's your code.  I just added 2 lines.  The Scene...etc.. line is from yours, right after that add the next 2 lines.  That's all I did.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question. How would you use this concept here:  for(int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y = y + 100); ?

Comment: you mean to draw more than 1 line?  Would you like them bound to 1/100 the height?

Comment: I mean like             for(int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y = y +20)
            {
                myPen.drawRect(20, y, 10, 10);
            }

Comment: How you you change your code for the rectangles so that more rectangles appear as you increase the height of the scene?

Comment: I would add a listener on scene height property and in the listener add the rectangles.  You should try it and ask a new question with some code.  `scene.heightProperty().addListener((obs, oldHeight, newHeight) -> {
            //do something with newHeight
        });`